# Avoid Focus on Mainwindow when showing it

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I'm currently working on a popup program in wpf that gets hidden either by `this.hide();` or `MainWindow1.WindowState = WindowState.Hidden` and "pops up" using `MainWindow1.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;`

My problem is, that I don't want the Mainwindow to gain any keyboard focus. 
So whatever program has the keyboard focus, when the popup gets shown, it should keep it.

I just want it that way, so people don't type entire emails in the not handeling Popup, just because they didn't notice it popping up.

Edit: 
I'm not trying to keep focus in any my own program windows but in other windows programs (e.g. Outlook)

Edit2:
Here is [a screenshot](http://s11.postimg.org/g6ztrizg3/Popup.png) from my Program, just to clear obscurities about the usage of the `PopUp` class.

Edit3: Maybe it's possible to set the keyboard focus back to the programm that was focused before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wpf prevent Popup window from removing the focus of an Textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929133/wpf-prevent-popup-window-from-removing-the-focus-of-an-textbox)

Comment: I have feeling, this shouldn't be a standard window. Maybe [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) will do?

Comment: @Novitchi S nope it is not, because I'm not trying to keep focus in my own program but in external ones.

Comment: @Sinatr What do you mean by that? I already searched for a PopupWindow or something but i did not find anything. Maybe its Forms?

Comment: @Marv, click [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) (it is hidden in my previous comment ^^). See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11499932/1997232) question.

Comment: @Sinatr Oh my bad sorry, kinda stressed here. I looked at it but i think that gets me to a bigger problem, I need the Popup to be my mainwindow, is that even possible? I'll try around a little, thanks so far :)

Comment: @Sinatr This neither works for me, because I need to design the popup window :/

Comment: `PopupWindow` has content (`Child`) property, where you can put your `UserControl`. I don't remember for sure, but I think you **can't have an input** at all in popup window. This can be solved by creating a normal window when popup is clicked I think. Just ideas. You can have all copyrights.

Comment: @Sinatr I have uploadet an link of my Mainwindow, which is also the "Popup" window, I hopeit clears out what im trying to do..^^

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)". BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advantage". That doesn't even make _sense_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is (as it seems) too easy, all you need to do is:

```
MainWindow1.Showactivated = false;
this.Show();
```

This will show the MainWindow while the focus is kept on whatever program had the focus before the MainWindow appeared.

Answer (score 0):

> so people dont type entire emails in

I would recommend that you set the main page controls, or their container, `Enabled` property to `false` when the popup is running and reverse when it is not. Hence focusing the user to the popup until its acknowledged.

Comment: This does, unfortunatly, not prevent the window from gaining focus when showing up.

Comment: @Marv True. I have updated the post to reflect what that would avoid.

Comment: Yea, that is correct, but that was just to illustrate what problem I want to solve. I meant that they dont type thier emails in my Window by accident instead of the email program itself, because it just popped up without them noticeing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you purpose is to show a notification form, check that component: [Windows Forms Toolkit](https://wftoolkit.codeplex.com/) NotificationForm

Comment: No, I just want my Mainwindow to Popup without having keyboard focus on it.